How to fix KMP issue - Please initialize at least one Kotlin target in 'composeApp (:composeApp)' or 'shared'?
I am facing this issue when trying to update Kotlin from 1.9.23 to 2.0.0 in compose multiplatform project.
Updated version of Kotlin in my libs.versions.toml file
kotlin = "2.0.0"
compose = "1.6.1"


The issue lies with Compose version 1.6.1, which does not support Kotlin 2.0.0. To resolve this, you need to update to Compose version 1.6.11.
Here's how you can do it:
Open your libs.versions.toml file.
Update the version numbers as follows:
kotlin = "2.0.0"
compose = "1.6.11"

